# Admin email notifications when new customer register

Tags: magento-1.9, user, group, adminnotification

I want that when a new customer is registered on the my magento site, the admin was notified by email of the new customer registration.
Tell us how to do it better?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an observer on the `customer_register_success` event.

Then access the customer object in your model:

```
public function my_cool_function($observer)
{
    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

    //Do whatever you want here
}
```

And here is some reading about how to create an email template and programmatically send it:
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-custom-emails/

Comment: Without observer possible? because strangely enough, in other CMS notification administrator has new default about user/customers why no in Magento?

Answer (score 5):

The [customer activation](https://github.com/Vinai/customer-activation) module from Vinai not only has this functionality but also allows you to specify the template used when emailing the admin user on customer registration.

It has a nice admin interface and can be set up on a store level.

[image: admin config]

In the background is uses the event `customer_save_after`

Comment: but i need notification administrator when new customer register, activation in my store will be in manually, possible to use the module for my requirements?

Comment: Even though this will probably do the job, I would really not advise installing an extension for such a small feature. It literally takes a few lines of codes to implement what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Magento 2 and want to stay informed about all the events in your store, you can try this extension by Magenest:http://store.magenest.com/magento-2-admin-email-notification.html 
It cover a lots of key events like new registration, new order, new review... The email you receive will also contain basic information about the event. Here is a template email when a customer register to your store:[image: New Registration] 
Feel free to have a look there (it is compatible with 2.1 too!).